# I don't know how to express such sentence correctly

Tags: sentence-construction

Here is the situation:

Someone made me change the content of a design just one day before deadline, but I gave him the design 2 months ago. He should let me know earlier, not the day before deadline.

So what I want to express is like: "Please don't let me change the design until the day before deadline", I don't know whether it is right, how to use this sentence correctly? Thanks.

Comment: "Please don't ask me to change the design one day before the agreed deadline."

Comment: This should be the answer, yes?

Comment: @Andrew That makes sense. But I still want to know how to emphasize that he didn't give me feedback until the day before deadline. Thanks!

Comment: [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask your question. They should be able to help you formulate an appropriate message. You can always bring it back here so that we can sort out any spelling and grammar, but I doubt if that will be necessary.

Comment: My suggestion would be: "Please try to avoid last-minute changes in the future, as we do need time to deliver the best design possible."  You could also use "Eleventh Hour" instead of "last-minute", but it's a less common usage.  You could also be more pointed in explaining that he's making this more difficult than it has to be, but you have to use your own judgement to decide how polite to be to this guy.

Answer (score 1):

You say "someone made me change ... a design".

Made me = ordered me, commanded me, coerced me, forced me

Therefore, "let" is not correct. Let = allow, permit.

You could say:

> Please don't **require me** to change the design one day before the deadline.

or

> Please don't **expect me** to change the design one day before the deadline.

The second one is very close to a *refusal* to change the design. If you are not politely refusing to make the change, don't use that version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the second version is more polite than the first one?

Comment: @Jay: Do you understand what the word **refusal** means?